# lists of tuples by a tuple element?

Tags: python, nlp, tuples, part-of-speech

I have a problem on matching the part of speech pos pattern.
we had a rules of preposition phrase pattern such as NN + IN + NN, VBG + IN + NN or ADJ + IN + NN.

The idea is extract the pattern from any given sentence and do matching with the define rules above, if matched then return True.

example extracted from sentence:
 sent_pos = [('increasing', 'VBG'), ('of', 'IN'), ('mutation', 'NN')]
match with either 
 rules1 = [('', 'VBG'), ('', 'IN'), ('', 'NN')]
 or 
 rule2 = [('', 'NN'), ('', 'IN'), ('', 'NN')]
 or 
 [('', 'ADJ'), ('', 'IN'), ('', 'NN')]

result return True.

It is possible in python code?

Thanks appreciated for your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure if this is what you are looking for because I don't know if the order of the patterns is always the same in rule1, rule2 and rule3, but try this:

```
def function():

   sent_pos = [('increasing', 'VBG'), ('of', 'IN'), ('mutation', 'NN')]
   rule1 = [('', 'VBG'), ('', 'IN'), ('', 'NN')]
   rule2 = [('', 'NN'), ('', 'IN'), ('', 'NN')]
   rule3 = [('', 'ADJ'), ('', 'IN'), ('', 'NN')]

   rules = [rule1, rule2, rule3]

   for element in rules:
        counter = 0
        for i in range(len(sent_pos)):
            if sent_pos[i][1] == element[i][1]:
                counter += 1
        if counter == len(sent_pos):
            return True
   return False
```

Comment: Thanks Ton1!this is extract what i want. I was searching is there any way that can do pattern matching between POS..